# how to combine ListView and actionBar

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar

I'm want to have a layout containg an actionBar and a listview of names.
The point is that when i try to combine both action bar and listview i get something wired:
the action bar is shown every each line of the list

( i'm using the following sample [Code](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) for the listview implementation:

and for the action bar i'm using :

```
      <com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    style="@style/ActionBar" />
```

please can someone tell me what's wrong

Comment: You shouldn't need to declare the action bar in XML like that. It will display automatically if the `<activity>` tag in the Android Manifest has the attribute `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"`. Can you check if this is the case?

Comment: i'm not using the default action Bar

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set the ActionBar on the XML? Android activates by default the ActionBar for all the Activities in the devices that use API 11 or later. I could explain you the basics, but I think that you'll learn better in [the official documentation page from Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

So you'll only need to add the ListView in the layout, and if you configure the ActionBar like in the documentation, Android handles automatically its creation.

See ya!